# Python Regular Expression: why does this not work?

Tags: python, regex, substitution

This does not give me an error nor an answer.

```
re.sub('\\.(\\W|\\.)*[o0](\\W|[o0])*', '*', '..........................................')
```

Why does it behave like so? Also, if I reduce the amount of 'periods', then it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 5):

You have no `o` or `0` in your input string, yet your regular expression requires at least one of those characters to be there (`[o0]`).

```
>>> re.compile('\\.(\\W|\\.)*[o0](\\W|[o0])*', re.DEBUG)
literal 46
max_repeat 0 65535
  subpattern 1
    branch
      in
        category category_not_word
    or
      literal 46
in
  literal 111
  literal 48
max_repeat 0 65535
  subpattern 2
    branch
      in
        category category_not_word
    or
      in
        literal 111
        literal 48
```

Update: Your regular expression is suffering from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html); avoid the nested character-class-or-character-set combination in a group with a wildcard (the `branch .. or` parts inside a `max_repeat` listed above). You can put character classes inside a character set to avoid this.

Also note, that you can use the `r''` raw string notation to avoid all the escaped backslashes.

The following works:

```
re.sub(r'\.[\W\.]*[o0][\Wo0]*', '*', '..........................................')
```

because it compiles to:

```
>>> re.compile(r'\.[\W\.]*[o0][\Wo0]*', re.DEBUG)
literal 46
max_repeat 0 65535
  in
    category category_not_word
    literal 46
in
  literal 111
  literal 48
max_repeat 0 65535
  in
    category category_not_word
    literal 111
    literal 48
```

Note that now the branches are gone.

Comment: I understand, and I do not expect the string to be matched. But why does it not give me an answer? (it seems like it's running an infinite loop, or gets stuck or something)

Comment: @SquallLeohart: that's an important detail; catastrophic backtracking will do that to you..